# Show rest XML file item attributes based on dropdown selection

Tags: php, html, xml, list

I have an XML file. I need on "Grad" selection to show values from Firma and BrojTelefona attributes, somewhere on the right side of Option list. As text.

HTML:

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="">
    <?php
    echo "<select>";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('adler.xml');
            foreach ($xml->record as $item)
            {
                 echo "<option value='".$item->Grad."'>" . $item->Grad . "</option>";
            }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
</form>
</html>
```

My XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <Firma>TD electronic</Firma>
        <BrojTelefona>034 715 445</BrojTelefona>
        <Grad>Arandjelovac</Grad>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Firma>Lihno d.o.o.</Firma>
        <BrojTelefona>011 848 5705</BrojTelefona>
        <Grad>Batajnica</Grad>
    </record>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I would like to do that with jquery or ajax, to be inline. Searching on net all day. 
Only thing i have found is similar but with mysql data not xml.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: If you like to do it with jquery and ajax, I would recommend that you study it properly, go through some tutorials and try something. SO isn't a free coding service where you just tell us what you want and we do it. You need to do the proper research and actually make some attempts before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution.

```
 <html>
<head>
<script>
function show(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","get.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <?php
     echo '<select onchange="show(this.value)">';
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('adler.xml');
            foreach ($xml->record as $item)
            {
                 echo "<option value='".$item->Grad."'>" . $item->Grad . "</option>";
            }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
</form>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Servis Adler uređaja za </b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And get.php file

```
<?php
 $q=$_GET["q"];

 $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
 $xmlDoc->load("adler.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('Grad');

for ($i=0; $i<=$x->length-1; $i++) {
  //Process only element nodes
  if ($x->item($i)->nodeType==1) {
    if ($x->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue == $q) {
      $y=($x->item($i)->parentNode);
    }
  }
}

$record=($y->childNodes);

for ($i=0;$i<$record->length;$i++) { 
  //Process only element nodes
  if ($record->item($i)->nodeType==1) {
    echo("<b>" . $record->item($i)->nodeName . ":</b> ");
    echo($record->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
    echo("<br>");
  }
}
?>
```